# failbit getting set with ifstream object, what can be the cause?

Tags: c++

I have written a small C++ program to set a property in a text file. The implementation is as following:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string PROPFILE = "./propfile";
const string TEMPFILE = PROPFILE + ".tmp";

int setProp(const string &key, const string &val) {

    try {
        ifstream original(PROPFILE, ios::in);
        ofstream tempfile(TEMPFILE, ios::out | ios::trunc);

        for (string line; getline(original, line); ) {
            if (line.compare(0, key.size(), key) == 0 && line[key.size()] == '=') {
                tempfile << key << '=' << val << endl;
            } else {
                tempfile << line << endl;
            }
        }

        cout << "original.rdstate()" << original.rdstate() << endl;

        original.close();
        tempfile.close();

    } catch (ifstream::failure e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    if (rename(TEMPFILE.c_str(), PROPFILE.c_str()) != 0) {
        cout << "Could not move " + TEMPFILE << "to " << PROPFILE << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    try {
        return setProp(argv[1], argv[2]);
    } catch (logic_error) {
        cout << "Invalid args" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile and execute it from commandline via `./a.out TESTPROP TESTVALUE`, the value IS set as expected in propfile but rdstate() returns 6 (which means failbit and eofbit are set), I can't understand why are they getting set, can somebody explain ?

Contents of propfile before running `./a.out TESTPROP TESTVALUE` are:

```
TESTPROP=NOTHING
```

After running the progam:

```
TESTPROP=TESTVALUE
```

I'm just a student, please don't mind if it's a dumb question :)

Comment: If you have an array with a size known at time of compilation, and that can't change size, why allocate it dynamically? And when reading lines from a file, why not use `std::string` instead?

Comment: Oh, and for any array *or pointer* `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. So instead of using e.g. `*(argv + 1)` please use the more common (and usually easier to read and understand) `argv[1]` (which also is less to write). And *never* use any part of `argv` before checking `argc`!

Comment: Also, the [`std::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename) function will *never* throw a C++ exception. It's inherited from the standard C library.

Comment: Seems unlikely but maybe you have a line that is longer than 4095 characters.

Comment: OK, so I changed line == key to line.compare(1, key.size(), key) and it's working as expected, the property is changed in the file, but still failbit is set and there's no logic error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using C++ rename function from filesystem library which throws an error (I verified with IntelliSense).

Comment: @john I don't think it's the cause, I used a C++ string which dynamically allocates data for the string, still the failbit is set.

Comment: @JayminSuthar rename does not 'throw' an error, its a C function, and C does not have exceptions, so it cannot throw anything. Maybe you aren't using the word 'throw' in the correct sense. If rename detects an error it returns a non-zero value, that's what you should check. [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename)

Comment: @JayminSuthar You haven't made it very clear, what output do you actually see when you run the above code? Remove the rename code and say what the context of PROPFILE and TEMPFILE are before and after running the code.

Comment: The new standard library filesystem `rename` function (introduced in C++17) is [`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename). You're using [`std::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename). If IntelliSense claims you're using `std::filesystem::rename` it's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I corrected that and some other things pointed out by @john and updated the question. I've gotten the code to work correctly, but I really want to know what's the reason behind failbit getting set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, the failbit is set whenever there is a failure to read the expected value. Even if that failure is because of end of file.

For instance see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

> If no characters were extracted for whatever reason (not even the
>   discarded delimiter), getline sets failbit and returns.

Comment: OK, I understand it now, but now I wonder how can I check the streams health (errors, etc) ?

Comment: @JayminSuthar getline is never going to fail except in the case of some kind of read error. In that case you can check `bad()`. But for simple reading from a file I don't think it's worth it. What you should check however is whether you files open successfully, that can fail for all kinds of reasons.